# Python program to remove double entries from line

Tags: python

i have the following function built to sort through lines, then per line, it sorts the content within the line into numerical values.

lines like this:

```
67:1 45:1 67:1 89:1
31:1 89:5 45:1 23:1
```

code:

```
with open("SVM/svm-pos-train.txt") as f, open("SVM/svm-pos-train2.txt", 'w') as out:
                for line in f:
                    line = line.split()
                    line.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.split(':')[0]))
                    out.write(" ".join(line) + '\n')
```

how do i edit this so that also removes the duplicates from the line, like this:

```
 45:1 67:1 89:1
 23:1 31:1 45:1 89:1
```

i been searching and trial/(much) error, but no luck.

Comment: should 67:1 and 67:2 be considered as same?

Comment: @oleg yes, i should have thought of that

Comment: in this case ```set(line.split())``` will not work

Comment: @oleg did'nt understand why set will not work.

Comment: @oleg their answer will do for now, for now the 1 is always the same.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal because `set(['67:1', '67:2 ']) != set(['67:1'])`. I don't know what is expected behaviour but I see that `int(x.split(':')[0])` is matter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

```
line = line.split()
line = list(set(line))
```

`set` returns an un-ordered collection of unique elements, then convert it back to list and then sort the list.

**Edit:**

```
line = line.split()
line = list(set(line))
out.write(" ".join(sorted(line, x: (int(x.split(':')[0]), int(x.split(':')[1])))) + '\n')
```

Comment: I'd add a `sorted()` to that (lexicographic ordering should be fine).

Comment: i'd add `' '.join(sorted(line))`

Comment: for some reason it puts them all in order, but not the last digits, for some reasons thats the lowest `1046:1 1808:1 2034:1 3283:1 3636:1 3710:1 3906:1 3911:1 4459:1 848:1 859:1`

Comment: Guess lexicographic ordering is not quite fine. `sorted(line, key=lambda x: int(x.split(':')[0]))`

Comment: Also, `set` isn't really a function, it's a type. It just happens that you can initialize it from an iterable.

Comment: @voithos updated my answer, however there is still a glitch with the second part after the [:] symbol. Will be updating it as soon as I resolve that issue as well.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal: If you want to include the second part in the sorting, you can just add it in a tuple, although you'll get some duplication: `key=lambda x: (int(x.split(':')[0]), int(x.split(':')[1])`

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal: You can also pull that key function out to a separate `def`, to avoid the duplicate `.split`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is helpful:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open("d1.txt") as f, open("d2.txt", 'w') as out:
    for line in f:
        fields = line.split()
        set_ = set(fields)
        list_ = list(set_)
        list_.sort()
        out.write(" ".join(list_) + '\n')
```

Comment: same for you :( ` 1610:1 1662:1 1797:1 1948:1 2561:1 3238:1 4295:1 4518:1 848:1 894:1` it doesnt sort them in increasing order